# Running a python file from Java

Tags: java

I searched for how to run  python from java and found  this code

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
     Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
     Process p1 = 
     runtime.exec("C:\\Python27\\Python  C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\py
     \\pythonfile.py");
}
```

it works if the results are String or int but my python code open a bmp image and  Process it and create new image,i don't went the image to return to java as result,i just went to send the image name from java and python file do the Process and create the new image.

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("6.bmp")
pixels = im.load()
 ...Some processes...
im.save("newim.bmp")
```

it give:

```
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

But there is no result, no image.

Comment: ``runtime.exec("C:\\Python27\\PythonC:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\py\\pythonfile.py");`` no space? ``runtime.exec("C:\\Python27\\Python C:\\Users\\acer\\Desktop\\py\\pythonfile.py");``

Comment: there is space,  it didn't appear

Answer (score 0):

> But there is no result, no image.

First, add error reporting to ensure you are really saving any image file. But if you do that correctly, the I would say that your issue is path related and you are simply saving your image in different folder that you think uou save into. Chceck what is your working dir for python script, i. e. `print(os.getcwd())`. Alternatively ensure your python script uses pull, absolute path for saving, so working dir no longer matters.

Comment: print(os.getcwd()) give C:\Users\acer\Desktop\py it's the file where i save the image in,and about the image saving it's work when i run the python code alone